# How to get rid of varying zeros in a column in R?

Tags: r

I have a df1:

```
Story     Score
1        00678
2         0980
3         1120
4        00067
5         0091
6          123
7          234
8         0234
9        00412
```

and I would like to get rid of all beginning 0s to have a df2:

```
Story     Score
1        678
2        980
3        1120
4        67
5        91
6        123
7        234
8        234
9        412
```

Comment: `as.numeric(df$Score)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `Score` column be text, you could use `sub` here:

```r
df$Score <- sub("^0+", "", df$Score)
```

If you intend for `Score` to be treated and used as numbers, you also might be able to just cast it to numeric:

```r
df$Score <- as.numeric(df$Score)
```